# I'm trying to plot two data features on log-log plot on seaborn. How do fit a line for this correlation?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

```
%matplotlib inline
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'State':['Alabama', 'California', 'Delaware', 'Texas','Oregon','Arizona'],
        'Cases':[20, 210, 19, 1800, 25, 8020],
        'Deaths':[1,50,3,200,5,300]}

df_state = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_state.head(10))

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
splot=sns.regplot(x=df_state["Cases"],y=df_state["Deaths"])
splot.set(xscale="log",yscale="log")
splot.set(xlim=(1, 10000))
splot.set(ylim=(1, 10000))
```

For above code, I'm not able to get a line fit.
Please help me understand the reason.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JA5G.png)

Comment: Do you see a line when the scales are not set to `log`?

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @jcaliz: Yes, when in linear axis, I see a line fit

Comment: @rpanai: Here you go:
https://easyupload.io/ukvzh4

Comment: Please update your question with the code.

Comment: @rpanai: Done, updated question to contain an 'mcve'

Comment: @rpanai: Yes, this answers my question. Thank you. I have accepted my question as duplicate